# MIPS practice in writing lists of number

Tags: mips

As the question required below,

Write a program in MIPS32 assembly language which reads a positive integer N and prints out the following:
1
12
123
1234
12345
...
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... N

Here is my code shown below:

```
    .data
word:   .asciiz "Please enter a random row: \n"
    .text
    .globl main

main:   
    la $a0, word        # load word
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 1           # service 1 is print integer
    move $a0, $t0       # move register to be printed into argument 
register $a0
    syscall

    lw $s0, row         # $s0 = row
    addi $s0, $s0, -1   # for accommodating loop condition
    li $s1, 1           # set i = 1
    li $s2, 1           # set j = 1


loop1:
    blt $s0, $s1, Exit  # for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    addi $s1, $s1, 1    # i++
    li $s2, 1           # resets j to 1 after every iteration of for 
loop
    move $a0, $t0       # move register to be printed into argument 
register $a0
    j loop2             # executing the nested for loop


loop2:
    blt $s1, $s2, loop1 # for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    li  $v0, 1          # read_double => scanf("%d")
    move $a0, $t0       # move register to be printed into argument $a0
    syscall
    j loop2


   li $v0, 10           # loading exit code
   syscall              # execute exit
```

As I tend to run it through, then I still could not achieve the expected outcome.

Comment: What is the assignment? Write C code to do this? Write MIPS code to do this? Or translate existing C to MIPS? In any way, please show your own effort and ask a more specific question. Nobody will (or should) just provide a free code writing service to you. Especially not for doing homework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'll write the code to do this:

Ask user for N value, & save.

Create a loop that will continue until N iterations (see conditional branching)

For N iterations, save the value 1, 1+=1, ... N in the register.

Remember that each word is 4 bytes. Make sure you are changing where you are accessing your register to save  your values correctly, or else they will overwrite each other.

Use another loop to print all values (again, conditional branching).

If you want help with code, try writing some first. :-)

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. Now I've provide my coding above, hope that u could give me some feedback about it.